# What is the reason for the PHPMailer error stream_select(): unable to select?

Tags: php, phpmailer

**edit at 11/24/2022：The problem I solved, but the cause is not found, it may be a problem with the PHP source code. I re-downloaded the source code from the official PHP website and overwrite it, the problem disappeared.**

My local environment is windows 10, PHPMailer will report this error in PHP 5.6, but it is normal in 7.0 and above, I haven't learned socket, I don't know how to troubleshoot this error.

**There are two kinds of errors.**

The first one is

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_select(): unable to select [11]: No such file or directory

**this error is in the case of tls protocol, port 25.**

The second one is

> Connection failed. error #2: stream_select(): unable to select [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable.

**this error occurs in the case of ssl protocol, port 465.**

Both are caused by stream_select in PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php at line 1228.

**debugging data**

> Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.qq.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
> Connection: opened
> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_select(): unable to select [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable (max_fd=772) [\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 1228]
> SMTP -> get_lines(): select failed (stream_select(): unable to select [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable (max_fd=772))
> SERVER -> CLIENT:
> Connection: closing due to error
> Connection: closed
> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: The "example" is my intentional change, I have replaced it as you suggested.

Comment: can you telnet to that SMTP IP and port, to check the connectivity?

Comment: Also, why use so outdated ver of PHP?

Comment: The audience of this project is some webmasters who are obsessed with PHP5.6, and I had to develop with PHP5.6. And I want to know the root cause of the problem, because I saw some people in GOOGLE who had the same problem with PHP 7.3, but no solution.

Comment: I tried to start a remote login to port 25 and it returned "220 newxmesmtplogicsvrszb6-0.qq.com XMail Esmtp QQ Mail Server." and the same code works fine to send mail in PHP version 7+.

Comment: You can also enable DEBUG for PhpMailer, to see thee whole trace of the connection, TLS or other issues..

Also check/try the temp solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741012/2291328 to see if it will work without verifying the SSL ... maybe the Cert Authorities are old on the server initiating the connection?

Comment: I remember that this was a tricky issue at the time. Have you looked at the code, comments, and links around [the area where this happens](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/8b6386d7417526d1ea4da9edb70b8352f7543627/src/SMTP.php#L1228)?

Comment: It would help to debug if you could paste some code. See how you initialize your mailer client for example